# How to close a url/website/tab using google chrome add-on?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So, imagine a person opening an online gaming website(for example krunker.io) in chrome, and what I want to know is whether there is a way to detect if a url(in this case "https://krunker.io/*") is open and to immediately close the tab(or the browser) using a Google Chrome addon(or even an outside application is fine).

The `window.close()` method does not work, as the person him/herself is the one who opens the tab/window, not the application

Comment: You can use [webNavigation API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) + chrome.tabs.remove. See also the [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Answer (score 0):

To close a tab, you can use the [chrome.tabs.remove](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-remove) method.

```
// retrieve the id of the tab to close
$tabToCloseId = retrieveIdOfTabToClose(); //To write by yourself
chrome.tabs.remove($tabToCloseId);
```